# Какие существуют варианты получения и обработки набора записей?

Tags: sql, база-данных, windows, postgresql, shell

Скажем есть табличка (левая):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно создать четыре таблицы и положить туда данные из исходной по какому либо признаку например по группирующей колонке (буква) и четности/нечетности (цыфра).

Можно было просто написать скрипт например на php и с помощью циклов и условий сделать то что нужно. Но меня интересует можно ли это осуществить только лишь используя только саму СУБД, скажем написать sql-запрос и подать его на вход клиенту подключенному к этой базе.

Если есть, что то лучше, чем то что я себе представляю, то рад услышать ваше мнение по этому поводу.

СУБД postgre. ОС windows.

Comment: Можно. Для каждой новой таблицы придётся создать запрос на создание (CREATE TABLE) и копирование в неё записей (INSERT .. SELECT). Либо по одному запросу с одновременным копированием данных (CREATE TABLE ... AS ...) Если хочется это выполнить "одним пакетом" - можно оформить в виде процедуры.

Comment: @Akina то есть можно написать только один sql скрипт который можно однократно выполнить не используя стороннее ПО, правильно я понял?

Comment: Абсолютно верно.

Comment: Я даже больше скажу - если вы напишете скрипт "например на php", который будет выполнять эту задачу - он будет грубо говоря содержать в себе искомый SQL скрипт, обернутый php кодом.

Comment: @Darth не-е-е, он же вообще изначально собирался все записи по одной через PHP протащить...

Comment: @Akina почему вы меня опять позорите? )))))) ничо я по одной записи не собирался тащить! Почему вы за меня думаете?

Comment: @Akina Поэтому я написал "грубо говоря". Даже если "по одной записи таскать" - имея на руках все необходимые для этого запросы, можно легко и быстро избавится от PHP, переписав код в процедуру SQL, как в написали в первом комментарии

Comment: Полагаю, четыре новые таблицы не нужны. Нужен просто запрос, возвращающий данные, сгруппированные по какому-либо признаку. В этом и состоит суть СУБД: группировать и фильтровать данные.

Comment: @perfect А вот это Ваше *помощью циклов и условий* что. не предполагает вытаскивание всех данных на клиента и их поштучную обработку? Но вообще **AlexanderPetrov** скорее всего прав - достаточно наштамповать необходимое количество представлений и не плодить дубликатов данных, да ещё размазанных по куче однотипных таблиц.

Comment: @Akina вАШЕ предполжение не верно. потому что меня попросили сделать это через php. А я не согласен с этим. Я хочу это сделать с помощью процедурного языка и поскольку опыта у меня в этом нет я задал его удостоверится в правильности своего решения что бы зайти в тупик. Помогли, спасибо вам, можете дальше гадать на магическом шаре о чем я думаю.

Comment: ~не (это я ошибку поправляю, что бы вы меня не критиковали, а то вдруг вы и подумаете какой он не грамотный даже слова путает АЙ Я ЙАЙ)

Answer (score 1):

Сходу могу предложить два варианта.

1. Сделать 4 оператора INSERT INTO TABLE_n ... SELECT FROM TABLE_0 WHERE ... и обернуть это все в блок DO, чтобы был один оператор
2. Пройтись курсором по исходной таблице и в зависимость от значений выполнять INSERT в нужную таблицу.